# La tienda en Pretashop no se muestra o aparece en el navegador

Tags: php, xampp, prestashop, debian-9

tengo un problema y agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar, ya que no he encontrado información sobre el problema.

Tengo una tienda local en el sistema operativo windows y quise pasar la tienda a otro sistema operativo (debian9), hice el proceso normal, me envié la carpeta de la tienda y de la base de datos por correo, instale lampp en debian 9 y ya que el puerto 8080 estaba ocupado, pase apache al 9090 y la base de datos también la cambie al puerto 4438, luego:

1. cree una base de datos nueva llamada tiendaoralplus e importe la anterior.
2. Pase la carpeta de la tienda a htdocs y esta se llama tiendaOralPlus.
3. Se hicieron modificaciones en setting.ini.php
4. Se hicieron modificaciones en la tabla ps_shop_url.

Sin embargo cuando le doy localhost:9090/tiendaOralPlus esta no aparece, cree otra carpeta de prueba y si le doy localhost:9090/prueba me muestra lo que tiene esta carpeta.
La verdad no se que puede ser o si las configuraciones que hice al 3 y 4 están mal, he realizado muchos cambios pero nada ha funcionado.
Los cambios en el archivo Setting.ini.php son:

•   define('_DB_SERVER_' ,  'localhost' );

•   define('_DB_NAME_' ,  'tiendaoralplus' );

•   define('_DB_USER_' ,  'root'  );

•   define('_DB_PASSWD_ ' ,  ' ' );

Y en el archivo ps_shop_url:

•   domain: localhost:9090

•   domain_ssl: localhost:9090

•   physical_uri_ /tiendaOralPlus/

Cuando le doy  localhost:9090/tiendaOralPlus aparece todo en blanco y en el inspector no aparece nada de la tienda.

[image: Imágenes de la base de datos, carpeta donde esta la tienda y del navegador]

Comment: busca en el log de apache2 probablemente te falta configurar mas cosas, incluso habilitar el short tag de php

Comment: Voy a mirar, para ver si puede faltar algo, gracias

Comment: No se muestra nada, ya habilite short tag pero no genera nada ni se muestra nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que se presentaba era por permiso, como el sistema operativo era debian9 era necesario dar permisos a toda la ruta de donde esta ubicada la carpeta smarty de prestashop, en caso de que no funcione con la ruta, se debe dar los permisos a cada carpeta de esa ruta. Los permisos eran chmod 755 -R /var/www/html/tienda/cache/smarty. Después de generar los permisos se logra visualizar la tienda.

Comment: Podrías elaborar un poco más el cambio que hiciste, por favor? La idea es que a otros con el mismo problema les sirva tu solución